# Appcelerator Titanium external libraries

Tags: mobile, titanium, external, pixastic

I am using appcelerator titanium and i am trying to build a mobile app that allows you to change an imageview brightness and contrast by using touch events.

It is not possible by using Titanium standard features, so i am guessing if i can import some external libraries like pixastic that can help me do so.

is it possible? how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure. pixastic is a javascript library so just include it with

```
Ti.include("path/to/pixastic");
```

if you intent to write a native code for your algorithms you can enrich your project with a objective-c module (or java module).